# Roku Scenegraph SGDEX- Replace HDPosterURL variable

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am using a customer view, and I need to add a photo from the grid feed instead of the thumbnail. I cannot figure ut how to do this without changing the thumbnail.  Is there a way to keep the thumbnail intact, and add a sperate photo for the CustomView?
Below is the code.  Would like to replace thumbnail with another image.  Again, my app is a basic Roku SGDEX (scenegraph developer extensions) Custom + Screen

```
'''

'''parse from GridHandler
''' DetialsPosterUrl would be my custom image to replace the the thumbnail in the CustomView
function ParseMediaItemToNode(mediaItem as Object, mediaType as String) as Object
    itemNode = Utils_AAToContentNode({
        "id": mediaItem.id
        "title": mediaItem.title
        "hdPosterUrl": mediaItem.thumbnail
        "detailsPosterURL": mediaItem.detailsPoster
        "Description": mediaItem.shortDescription
        "Categories": mediaItem.genres[0]
    })


''' CustomView
sub ShowCustomView(hdPosterUrl as String)
    m.customView = CreateObject("roSGNode", "custom")
    m.customView.picPath = hdPosterUrl
    m.top.ComponentController.CallFunc("show", {
    view: m.customView
    })
end sub

'''deails view
sub OnDetailsContentSet(event as Object)
details = event.GetRoSGNode()
currentItem = event.GetData()
if currentItem <> invalid
    buttonsToCreate = []

    if currentItem.url <> invalid and currentItem.url <> ""
        buttonsToCreate.Push({ title: "Play", id: "play" })
    else if details.content.TITLE = "series" 
        buttonsToCreate.Push({ title: "Episodes", id: "episodes" })
    else if details.content.TITLE = "SERIES"
        buttonsToCreate.Push({ title: "Episodes", id: "episodes" })
    end if

    buttonsToCreate.Push({ title: "Details", id: "thumbnail" })   
'''
''' (more code irrevelant to topic)
'''
    else if selectedButton.id = "thumbnail"
    if details.currentItem.hdPosterUrl <> invalid then
        ShowCustomView(details.currentItem.hdPosterUrl)
    end if

'''
```

custom.xml

```
 ''''
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <component name="custom" extends="Group" >
    <interface>
      <field id="picPath" type="string" alias="thumbnail.uri" />
    </interface>
    <children>
     <Poster id="thumbnail" translation="[0,0]" width="1280" height="720" />
    </children>
 </component>
 ''''
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your "ShowCustomView" function I see You are setting the "picPath" to be "hdPosterUrl", right? But what does that mean? Please check do You have "picPath" field set up inside "custom" .xml file?
Check does it have "alwaysNotify" set to true. Is "picPath" used inside 
ComponentController "show" function to set up url of some poster for the "custom" component? Check how do You pass data from ComponentController to the custom view. Hope it will help.

EDIT:
Can You add different field `itemNode` to like this:

```
Utils_AAToContentNode({
        "id": mediaItem.id
        "title": mediaItem.title
        "hdPosterUrl": mediaItem.thumbnail
        "detailsPosterURL": mediaItem.detailsPoster
        "Description": mediaItem.shortDescription
        "Categories": mediaItem.genres[0]
        "ShortDescriptionLine1" : yourImageUrl
    })
```

Then use the "ShortDescriptionLine1" instead of `hdPosterUrl`.
I have used `ShortDescriptionLine1` since I assume that You are converting this to a regular, non custom content node. In that case You can use fields from this: [Content Metadata](https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/developer-program/getting-started/architecture/content-metadata.md) or You can add custom fields with [Update()](https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifsgnodechildren.md#updateaa-as-roassociativearray-as-void) function and not use fields from Content Metadata.

Comment: Yes, I do have hdPosterUrl in the pic path in both ShowCustomView function.  Below are the files.  the picPath looks like this inside the interface of the custom.xml.                      <field id="picPath" type="string" alias="thumbnail.uri" />

Comment: I have also added the full custom view to the original post for viewing.  thanks.

Comment: I have added some edits, can You check if they help?

Answer (score 0):

As your statement is conflicting(i.e. not clear whether you want to change the thumbnail or want to add a new node to display image), don't know what will be your preference. But both are possible. First you need to traceback to your custom component. After that, if you want to change thumbnail to show your required image, modify that node according to your need. If you want to add new node just add it everywhere where ever thumbnail node is added.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sorry I wasn't too clear.  I am familiar with how to change the Thumbnail.  The thumbnails are working fine with my Grid.  There is a "custom view" node that I want to add a different image to, that is not the Thumbnail.  I am not sure how to do that.  I have parsed HdPosterUrl which is the thumbnail.  I have also parsed detailsPosterUrl which is a different image.  I am not sure how to get detailsPosterUrl to show in the CustomView node.  I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Please check whether you have some nodes in your customView component, to bind with detailsPosterUrl.

Comment: It think that's park of the problem.  But I haven't yet figured it out.  It seems with scenegraph only HdPosterUrl will work. Even if I change everything, that I could find to detailsPosterUrl.  - I can't simply use the hdPosterUrl from the parsed feed as that is used for the actual thumbnail in the grid.